# \setmainfont breaks \DeclareMathOperator

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math

`\DeclareMathOperator` works fine without `\setmainfont`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\nabla}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\nabla \grad f$
\end{document}
```

[image: correct output]

However, as soon as I include the command `\setmainfont`, the `\DeclareMathOperator` stops working.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\nabla}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{texgyrebonum}
\begin{document}
$\nabla \grad f$
\end{document}
```

[image]

It happens with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure `\nabla` should be treated as an operator.

Comment: You don't have to use nabla as a TeX math operator. `\newcommand*\grad{\nabla}`, `\newcommand*\grad[1]{\nabla{#1}}` or may be `\newcommand*\grad{\mathop{}\!\nabla}` (or the other variant). But not a TeX matho operator.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. Doing that solves the problem.

Comment: By the way, `\DeclareMathOperator` is broken in `unicode-math`. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need to have such spacing.

```
\newcommand*\grad[1]{\nabla\mathord{#1}} % and use like \grad{f}
```

If you want to ensure a small space (like before differentials, for instance) you could add `\mathop{}\!`

```
\newcommand*\grad[1]{\mathop{}\!\nabla\mathord{#1}}
```

Of course you can drop the argument and the `\mathord{#1}` part, but I think it does no harm and is convenient here.